# on device face recognition - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, offline, face-detection, face-recognition

I have an app that takes all the images of the user (all the Assets from the Photo app). After that the app should run throw all the images and detect faces and return their facial landmarks, and then look in the database to see if there is any friend with the same landmark (recognizing friend faces), similar to what Facebook do on moments app and on the web. The app will then show all the photos that the friend appear in them. Important part of my app is the user privacy, so I would like to keep the entire process on the device, and not sending it to online service. Another benefit of keeping it on the device is that every user in my app can have thousands of images, and working with external service will be expansive and might low down the performance (if every image need to be sent to the server).

From the research that I done there are many online services (but they don't fit my requirements - keeping the process offline). There is also the CIDector that detect the faces, and then you can return few features such as eye location and mouth location (which I don't believe that is good enough for reliable recognition). I also heard about Luxand, openCV, and openFace, which are all on device recognition, but are C++ class, which make it difficult to integrate with swift project (the documentation are not very good, and don't explain how do integrate it to your project and how to perform face recognition on swift).

So my question is if there is any way to perform face detection that return the facial landmarks on the device?

- If not is there any other way or service I could use.

Also if there is any efficient and fast way to perform face detection and recognition, if a user could have thousand of images.

By the way, I am in early stage of development and I am looking for free services that I could use for the development stage.

Comment: Sounds a bit heavy for a mobile device. I would just go with a C++ library and see how well it runs on the device. Nothing worth doing is easy ;)

Comment: Isn't this feature already in the Photos app of iOS10?

Comment: Yes, @KevinGoedecke. I believe they called it Scene Classification. It works for faces and also for common basic objects, like dogs, mountains, and rivers.

Comment: Could I use it in my Own App? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think they provide an SDK or API for that feature. But it very much sounds like your trying to implement a functionality that's already there :/

Comment: @IdanAvivn did you find a solution for face recognition? I am researching in frame detection and recognition but I think iOS does not provided face recognition api yet or I am not sure may be there is a face recognition api for iOS .

Comment: i didn't find a solution yet. I figure out that if i want to use face recognition i will have to build it my self using OpenVC or Open face (free class of iOS). OpenVC offer many different methods for face recognition and detection. Its a bit hard to do it, and take a lot of time to figure out how to use it. I still didn't have time to work with it, but I am going to try it in the future.

Comment: Hello, @IdanAviv and Xcodian, I am also facing the same issue did you get any solution?

Comment: Hello.Did anyone find a solution ?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/NovatecConsulting/FaceRecognition-in-ARKit @IdanAviv

Answer (score 2):

iOS have native face detection in `CoreImage` framework that works pretty cool. You can as well detect eyes etc. Just check out this code, there's show how you can work with it.

```
func detect() {

guard let personciImage = CIImage(image: personPic.image!) else {
    return
}

let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy)
let faces = faceDetector.featuresInImage(personciImage)

// converting to other coordinate system
let ciImageSize = personciImage.extent.size
var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -ciImageSize.height)

for face in faces as! [CIFaceFeature] {

    print("Found bounds are \(face.bounds)")

    // calculating place for faceBox
    var faceViewBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(face.bounds, transform)

    let viewSize = personPic.bounds.size
    let scale = min(viewSize.width / ciImageSize.width,
                    viewSize.height / ciImageSize.height)
    let offsetX = (viewSize.width - ciImageSize.width * scale) / 2
    let offsetY = (viewSize.height - ciImageSize.height * scale) / 2

    faceViewBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceViewBounds, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale))
    faceViewBounds.origin.x += offsetX
    faceViewBounds.origin.y += offsetY

    let faceBox = UIView(frame: faceViewBounds)

    faceBox.layer.borderWidth = 3
    faceBox.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    faceBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    personPic.addSubview(faceBox)

    if face.hasLeftEyePosition {
        print("Left eye bounds are \(face.leftEyePosition)")
    }

    if face.hasRightEyePosition {
        print("Right eye bounds are \(face.rightEyePosition)")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I know that IOS have face detection. But I need a way to recognize the face, meaning I could say for example that the face in the image is Bob's face. And in order to do this I think I believe I need more information then what the CIFaceFeature provide. Do you know how could I do it with the built in detector.

Comment: ohhhh, you need face comparing. Actually I don't, never do that before. Hope you will find proper answer. Will rate your question.

Comment: @Volodymyr how can I use detection through a live camera instead of images in Assests .?